# Windows NLB not balanced

Tags: load-balancing, nlb

I set up a NLB cluster given two servers (WS 2008 R2). Each server has one NIC card which I set up for a static ip address. I assigned the cluster an internet name (MyCluster), and assigned it a static ip address. The third box is acting as a client sending TCP data (over WCF) to the cluster's IP I configured (static IP). I am observing the NLB cluster from the NLB manager at one of the nodes - both nodes are green, say started. However, I am only able to see traffic coming in to one of the NLB servers. When I suspend it, I see traffic going to the other NLB server, and so on. I was expecting traffic to be split equally between them. I can't figure out what I missed, any tips please?

If you need more detailed information please ask, not sure how much detail to put in here.

Thanks/.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a port rule created with a Filtering mode of multiple host will use single affinity.  In other words, multiple requests from the same client will get directed to the same host.  To see traffic going to both hosts try accessing the cluster from multiple clients.  You could also set the affinity to "none", but this can lead to other problems.

There's good information on the affinity parameter and how to use it in the NLB help file.